# Mapping through nested arrays in es6 javascript

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, object, nested

I have a simple array that I want to group it's objects by date so I used this function

```
  const groupedDates= Object.entries(
    items.reduce((acc, { product, price, type, date }) => {
      if (!acc[date]) {
        acc[date] = [];
      }
      acc[date].push({ product, price, type date });
      return acc;
    }, {})
  ).map(([date, items]) => ({ date, items }));
```

the array

```
  const items = [
    {
      id: 1,
      product: "milk",
      price: 10,
      type: "drink"
      date: "01/01/2022",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      product: "coca",
      price: 11,
      type: "drink"
      date: "01/01/2022",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      product: "pepsi",
      price: 20,
      type: "drink"
      date: "01/01/2024",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      product: "carrots",
      price: 30,
      type: "food",
      date: "01/01/2023",
    },
  ];
```

I got this result

```
{

0: [
 date: 01/01/2022,
 items : [
     0 : {
      id: 1,
      product: "milk",
      price: 10,
      type: "drink"
      date: "01/01/2022"
     }
     1 : {
      id: 2,
      product: "coca",
      price: 11,
      type: "drink"
      date: "01/01/2022",
     }
], 

1: [
 date: "01/01/2024",
 items : [
     0 : {
      id: 3,
      product: "pepsi",
      price: 20,
      type: "drink"
      date: "01/01/2024",
     }
],

2: [
  date: "01/01/2023",
  items: [
      0:{
      id: 4,
      product: "carrots",
      price: 30,
      type: "food",
      date: "01/01/2023"
   }
    ]
  ]
}
```

**Issue**: 
I cannot seem to figure out how to access items[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsuAm.png) when it exists.

**What I have tried** 
is the map below but it only returns the first level of items which is 0 and if I do items[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsuAm.png) it returns an error because not all arrays have a second item.

```
{groupedDates.map((obj) => (
     {obj.items[0].product}))}
```

**UPDATE**
I'd also like to get the total for each date so I can have a card that has the Date + The total + each item and it's individual price. After getting some help from @Nick, I've managed to output the date, the item and it's price, now I'm still missing the total price for the date.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific reason to have numeric keys? Would not it be more efficient if you have the key to be the date itself?

Comment: "01/01/2024":[{
      id: 4,
      product: "carrots",
      price: 30,
      type: "food",
      date: "01/01/2023"
   },]

Comment: yeah that could work too but it's not really the issue is it ?

Comment: something like `{groupedDates.map((obj) => obj.items.map(i => i.product))}` perhaps?

Comment: This works for me and does exactly what I want so yeah you can post your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate the items in each `obj` to get the list of products:

```js
const items = [
  { id: 1, product: "milk", price: 10, type: "drink", date: "01/01/2022" },
  { id: 2, product: "coca", price: 11, type: "drink", date: "01/01/2022" },
  { id: 3, product: "pepsi", price: 20, type: "drink", date: "01/01/2024" },
  { id: 4, product: "carrots", price: 30, type: "food", date: "01/01/2023" },
];

const groupedDates = Object.entries(
  items.reduce((acc, { product, price, type, date }) => {
    if (!acc[date]) {
      acc[date] = [];
    }
    acc[date].push({ product, price, type, date });
    return acc;
  }, {})
).map(([date, items]) => ({ date, items }));

const allProducts = groupedDates.map((obj) => obj.items.map(i => i.product))

console.log(allProducts)

const totalsByDate = groupedDates.map(({ date, items }) => (
  { [date] : items.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.price, 0) }
))

console.log(totalsByDate)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height:100% !important; top 0 }
```

Note I would make `groupedDates` an object with its keys being the dates; that will make looking up data for a given date much easier. For example:

```js
const items = [
  { id: 1, product: "milk", price: 10, type: "drink", date: "01/01/2022" },
  { id: 2, product: "coca", price: 11, type: "drink", date: "01/01/2022" },
  { id: 3, product: "pepsi", price: 20, type: "drink", date: "01/01/2024" },
  { id: 4, product: "carrots", price: 30, type: "food", date: "01/01/2023" },
];

const groupedDates = items.reduce((acc, { date, ...rest }) => {
    acc[date] = (acc[date] || []).concat({ ...rest })
    return acc;
  }, {})

console.log(groupedDates)

const allProducts = Object.values(groupedDates)
  .flatMap(arr => arr.map(obj => obj.product))

console.log(allProducts)

const totalsByDate = Object.entries(groupedDates).map(([ date, items ]) => (
  { [date] : items.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.price, 0) }
))

console.log(totalsByDate)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height:100% !important; top 0; }
```

Comment: there might me a small mistake here, in flatMap(arr ... ) it says arr is not defined

Comment: any idea on how to get the total for the prices of each date ?
```
  const getTotalByDate= groupedDates.forEach(function (i) {
    const sum = i.items.reduce(function (sum, elem) {
      return sum + elem.amount;
    }, 0);
    console.log(sum);
  });
```
This kind of does the job and it returns the total for each date but I cannot figure out how to output that

Comment: @DavidNy sorry about the `arr` issue, that was a typo which strangely still works in my browser. I've fixed that. I've also added a function to total values by date to each snippet. Let me know if that helps

Comment: no worries. 

I prefer working with the first reduce function, converting groupedDates to an object makes it a bit confusing. 

'' totalsByDate ''  that you suggested above works with the second method where groupedDates is converted to an object. It's just a bit confusing when you want to output that in a div. 

{groupedDates.map((obj) => obj.items.map(i => i.product))} not quiet sure how I can output the total of each date within the map function.

Maybe it'd be more simple to add a totalAmount in each array, so each array would be something like: date, items, total

Comment: @DavidNy I saw your other question, if you updated it with some sample HTML that you are trying to add the totals to, it would make it easier to answer

Comment: just updated it above

Comment: Not overly familiar with react, but maybe `<Typography variant="body2">{"E" + item.items.reduce((acc, i) => acc + i.price, 0)}</Typography>` after the map? I guess you'll need to put that in some sort of structure (`<Stack>`?) with the "Total" string as well

Comment: <Typography/> and <Stack/> are just MUI components